# findAll doesn't get object structure according to Includes Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have tables like `Medics`, `MedicalSpecialties` and `Users`. Models are define like:

**Users Model**

```
const Database = require('../sequelize');

const UserModel = Database
  .getInstance()


.define('users', {
    UserId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    FirstName: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    MiddleName: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    LastName: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    SecondLastName: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    ID: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    Email: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    Password: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    CellPhoneNumber: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    OtherPhoneNumber: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    Deleted: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.BOOLEAN
  });

module.exports = UserModel;
```

**Medical Specialties Model**

```
const Database = require('../sequelize');

const MedicalSpecialtyModel = Database
  .getInstance()
  .define('medicalspecialties', {
    MedicalSpecialtyId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    Description: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    CreatedUserId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'UserId'
      }
    },
    UpdatedUserId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'UserId'
      },
      allowNull: true
    },
    createdAt: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.DATETIME,
    updatedAt: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.DATETIME
  });

module.exports = MedicalSpecialtyModel;
```

**Medics Model**

```
const Database = require('../sequelize');

const MedicModel = Database
  .getInstance()
  .define('medics', {
    MedicId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    UserId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: false,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'UserId'
      }
    },
    MedicalSpecialtyId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'medicalspecialties',
        key: 'MedicalSpecialtyId'
      }
    },
    Code: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.STRING,
    CreatedUserId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'UserId'
      }
    },
    UpdatedUserId: {
      type: Database.FIELD_TYPE_ENUM.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'UserId'
      },
      allowNull: true
    }
  });

module.exports = MedicModel;
```

What I want to do is to get results with object parent child Representation like

```
[
    {
        "MedicId": 1,
        "Code": "test1",
        "user": {
          "UserId": 4,
          "FirstName": "John",
          "MiddleName": null,
          "LastName": "Doe",
          "SecondLastName": null,
        },
        "medicalspecialty": {
          "MedicalSpecialtyId": 3,
          "Description": "Doctor"
        }
    }
]
```

But instead I'm getting this result:

```
[
    {
        "MedicId": 1,
        "Code": "test1",
        "user.UserId": 4,
        "user.FirstName": "John",
        "user.MiddleName": null,
        "user.LastName": "Doe",
        "user.SecondLastName": null,
        "medicalspecialty.MedicalSpecialtyId": 3,
        "medicalspecialty.Description": "Doctor"
    }
]
```

This is how I'm pulling data:

```
static getAllMedics() {
    MedicModel.belongsTo(MedicalSpecialtyModel, {
      foreignKey: 'MedicalSpecialtyId'
    });
    MedicModel.belongsTo(UserModel, {
      foreignKey: 'UserId'
    });
    UserModel.belongsTo(MedicModel);
    MedicalSpecialtyModel.hasMany(MedicModel);

    const attributes = ['MedicId', 'Code'];
    return MedicModel.findAll({
      attributes,
      include: [{
        model: UserModel,
        attributes: ['UserId', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'SecondLastName'],
        where: {
          Deleted: false
        },
        required: true,
        nested: true
      }, {
        model: MedicalSpecialtyModel,
        attributes: ['MedicalSpecialtyId', 'Description'],
        required: true,
        nested: true
      }],
      raw: true
    });
  }
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4):

The `raw` property on a find call flattens the structure.

Basically do a find without `raw: true`.

You could get more info about it [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#raw-queries)

Comment: But If I remove it, I will get this error `(node:14825) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: result.get is not a function`, that is why I add it at first time.

Answer (score 1):

At the end it was my error.

When initializing Sequelize I had added the option `row: true`.

`new Sequelize(..., {
...,
row: true
})`

My apologies.